# Interpolating and estimating uncertainty

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

Let's say I have a gappy time series `x`, with a particular measurement through time. I also have a measure of uncertainty `sx` (say the standard deviation of `x` at a particular interval). I just basically want to gap-fill the time series, but I want to propagate the measurement uncertainty, and hopefully, the interpolation uncertainty. In the past, I have used Tikhonov regularisation to achieve this (i.e. adding a smoothness constraint), but I'd rather just use an out-of-the-box routine from scipy. I can see that the scipy spline interpolation routines take a smoothing parameter (that would be derived for `sx` here), but it doesn't calculate the interpolated series' uncertainty.

I'm asking because I don't think it's a trivial calculation, and to see if anyone know whether this capability is available.

Comment: One way of doing this is to use a gaussian process.  Have a look at scikits.learn: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/gaussian_process.html (Also, kriging is a specific type of guassian process, and it's a method you'll come across in the interpolation world a lot)

Comment: For a full example using scikit-learn: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/gaussian_process/plot_gp_regression.html

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that, but I was hoping the scipy spline routines could provide uncertainty "out of the box".

Comment: Probably [OpenTURNS](http://www.openturns.org/) could help. As they say _OpenTURNS is a scientific library usable as a Python module dedicated to the treatment of uncertainties._ . It is developed by Innovation Works EADS and it is quite reliable. At least it has a documentation that could give you a hint.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean by "propagate the measurement uncertainty, and hopefully, the interpolation uncertainty", but if I understand you correctly, you have a noisy measurement and an additional information about uncertainty. If the noise is white noise, or can be whitened, then you could use a [Kalman filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter) to smoothen the regular measurement and to estimate measurements in gaps.

A Kalman filter uses a state model to predict future measurements and models the signal's white noise component using a covariance matrix. The uncertainty measure can be applied to modify the filter's "trust" weight between prediction and measurement. You can use the covariance matrix to determine a provisional uncertainty measure.

Comment: Well, in fact, I'd rather have a Kalman smoother than a filter, but I was asking whether scipy's Spline interpolation routines did take uncertainty into account (I guess you can calculate it, but might not be trivial!)

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help you with that, never used it.
A Kalman smoother is a special operating condition of the more general concept of Kalman filter.